# Quel est l'avis des institutions normatives sur la prononciation des noms étrangers ?

Tags: prononciation, noms-propres, standard

Je me souviens d'une discussion très embarrassante avec un allemand parlant pourtant français au moins aussi bien que moi.

> « Isaac Asimov `[izak.asimɔf ]` est vraiment celui que je préfère.
>   — Ah? Je ne le connais pas.
>   — Vraiment ? *Fondation*, *Robots* ?
>   — Ah ! Isaac Asimov `[ˈaɪzək ˈæzɨməv]`! »

Où manifestement le fait de franciser la prononciation nom de cet auteur a été source d'incompréhension. Quel est l'avis des institutions prescriptivistes habituelles à ce sujet ? Doit-on franciser ou essayer de conserver la prononciation originale ?

Comment: Comment prononcer en français à destination d'un Allemand un prénom hébreu initialement écrit en cyrillique et ensuite porté en anglais?

Comment: @mouviciel: En l'occurence l'Allemand en question étant un redoutable polyglotte : au choix.

Comment: Il me semble que les allemands tentent de conserver des prononciations proches de celles originales, alors que la France n'a aucune règle.  Je crois même que la prononciation de "Phuket" changeait même au cours du même reportage après le tsunami de 2004 : fuquet, puquet, fuquette, puquette, p'huquet, etc.

Comment: Alors moi je m'intéresse à la chanteuse islandaise Björk, dont le vrai nom est Björk Guðmundsdóttir, et la prononciation ˈpjœr̥k ˈkvʏðmʏntsˌtoʊhtɪr. Avis à tous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Je ne citerai pas d'autorité ici, je vais juste dire qu'il faut rendre à César ce qui appartient à César. Un français est à peine capable de prononcer Aille-ze'k Ézimeuve, et que dire alors de Mi'rahil Garbatch'of ou Dji/ang Ji\esh/i ?

Étant donné qu'il est manifestement impossible de conserver en français la prononciation d'origine, tout ce que l'on peut espérer est pour une langue donnée d'avoir des règles de transcription phonétique. Souvent les noms étrangers sont connus d'abord par écrit, et les français reconstruisent une prononciation vaguement étrangère en se basant sur les langues qu'ils connaissent et en essayant d'éviter les lettres muettes.

Comment: Si quelqu'un se demande de qui il parle : Tchang Kaï-chek.

Comment: @Evpok Pour les noms initialement écrits en cyrillique, comme Isaac Asimov (Исаак Озимов), l'orthographe est déjà traduite. Alors pour la prononciation, je ne vois pas pourquoi ça poserait problème!

Comment: Pour les noms cyrillique, il y a une retranscription pour chaque langue. En français, on traduirait par: "Isaac Ozimoff". En anglais on devrait traduire par: "Izaak Ozimov" mais le nom a changé en "Asimov" lors de son arrivée aux US et son prénom a été traduit par l'équivalent anglais.

Answer (score 7):

Je pense qu'il faut garder une attitude ouverte et pragmatique… D'autant plus que je dois faire plein d'erreurs de prononciation ! Comme tout le monde, vu qu'on ne connaît pas toutes les langues du monde. Je préférerais qu'on garde la prononciation originelle, quand on la connaît, mais l'usage, et l'ignorance, prévalent souvent.

Certains noms sont souvent prononcés, par exemple aux informations (télé, radio), donc il y a peu de problèmes. Les journalistes ont un petit livre expliquant comment prononcer les noms les plus courants… Encore faut-il qu'ils l'aient et qu'ils le consultent !

D'autres noms sont découverts par l'écrit, et si la prononciation n'est pas donnée, et si on ne connaît pas les règles spécifiques à la langue, on a tendance à prononcer à la française, ou peut-être à l'anglaise, dans certains cas (voyelles doublées, en général).

Par exemple, je découvre un logiciel nommé Vaadin, un nom finnois. En voyant ça, on peut prononcer à la française (`va-adin`), à l'anglaise, un a long, ou comme un natif, si on connaît la langue ou trouve une explication (souvent approximative) ou un [fichier sonore](http://fr.forvo.com/word/vaadin).

Autre exemple d'erreur courante : le japonais est souvent transcrit en *romaji* avec la méthode Hepburn, la plus courante, suivant des règles précises. Ainsi le son `sa` est toujours transcrit *sa*, et toujours prononcé de la même façon, quel que soit sa place dans le mot (il y a quelques exceptions comme le `u` final, mais passons).
J'essaie souvent d'expliquer que *wasabi* se prononce `wassabi` et pas `wazabi`, généralement sans succès… :-)
Si on parle à un japonais de *wazabi*, soit il ne va pas comprendre, soit il va faire un contresens (j'ignore si *wazabi* a un sens en japonais…).

Cela dit, j'ai toujours prononcé Isaak à la française (ou à ma sauce…), `isa-ak`, vu que quand je l'ai découvert, j'étais nul en anglais et ignorais comment ça se prononce…

Chose amusante, je pense que tout le monde parle du groupe U2 en disant `ioutou`, mais on entendra des prononciations différentes pour UB40 ou B-52…
Par contre, tout le monde (ou presque) prononcera USA en épelant en français plutôt qu'en anglais.

Answer (score 6):

Ca va dépendre de ta définition de 'doit' :)

Très tôt<sup>#</sup> pendant mon apprentissage du français, j'ai compris qu'il fallait franciser les noms propres quand on parle (ou quand on écoute) si on veut avoir une chance d'être compris (ou de comprendre).

*<sup><sup>#</sup>C'était quelqu'un qui me demandait si j'aimais '[Feelco Leens](http://www.google.com/search?pq=phil%20collins)'...</sup>*

Answer (score 1):

Je suis assez d'accord avec Gilles. Je pense que les informations nous parviennent d'abord à l'écrit. La prononciation est alors plus ou moins de la réalité en fonction des médias qui relaient cette information.

Dans tous les cas, à mon avis il faudrait conserver la prononciation initiale.