# How to textually describe the pronunciation of spanish names with "oi"?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, noms-propres, espagnol

There are many names and family names in Spanish that contain the combination of vowels "oi" (Roilán, Moisés, Loinaz, etc.). When these names are pronounced in French, the original pronunciation is completely changed. Is there a way to modify the spelling so that I can describe the Spanish pronunciation to a French speaker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it is pronounced [oi] as I think, you just have to use a [dieresis ¨](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29) ([*tréma*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9ma) in French). It already exists in French, for instance my first name is Lo‌**ï**‌c, pronounced [loik], as opposed to Lo‌**i**‌c [lwak].

Comment: Another example: "Moses" from the Bible is "Moïse" in French and "Moisès" is Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

In French, this pronunciation often goes along with *y* in written text (I think of [“*oyez*”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/is-ouir-used-at-all-anymore/) and *“royal”*), you can use that if you want to describe it.

It's also the pronunciation of *-ille* in French, which forces the *i* out of any bigram it could form with the preceding vowel, as in “*paille*” (and arguably, in “*corbeille*”).

I have the feeling there's something about *half-vowels* missing in this answer, but I can't type what I don't know about.

As [@Evpok mentions](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2493/9495), if you want to force the spelling to be well-pronounceable, use a dieresis on the *i*, but I'm not fond of this solution. You'll have a hard time explaining it's a Spanish name if you add this kind of punctuation to it¹. I'd just introduce it well-pronounced, or correct the first one mis-pronouncing it, and that'd be a good occasion to discuss [foreign pronunciation](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/pourquoi-devrait-on-dire-handball-a-lallemande) or [proper nouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/les-noms-propres-etrangers-doivent-ils-etre-prononces-a-la-francaise), maybe.

---

¹ dieresis in Spanish are rather uncommon, to say the least.

Comment: The only two words my dictionary know that contain `oille` are *oille* (old) `[ɔjə]` and *boille* (swiss) `[bɔjə]`, are you really suggesting it would be sounded `[oi]` by French speakers??

Comment: Btw, the OP never said it would change the spelling of these names. The question is clear, he wants to know how this same combination of sounds could be written in French in order to explain how it is pronounced, *oï* is the perfect answer.

Comment: Note to readers: *ill* is usually sounded either `[j]` or `[il]`.

Comment: 1. If I didn't mention them, it's because in this particular case, I have no idea, but **I**'d probably pronounce them like “oy”, yeah. For 2 words I never heard about before, one being foreign, I'm not changing my rule of thumb. ❚ 2. Even though I'm not getting what's *it* in your comment (a *he* or “putting a dieresis” ?), if “Is there a way to modify the spelling” isn't about changing spelling, *je sais pas ce qu'il te faut*. ❚ 3. Thx. 4. Thanks. I'll revise that someday, for now it's really code to me.

Comment: Don't you make a difference between `[ɔj]` (“oy”) and `[oi]` (“oï”)?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Not really. If you mean the *i* is not totally pronounced in all its acuteness in `[ɔj]`, then I see what you mean, and I think that's my half-vowel lack of knowledge (reader, see the [`[j]`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant) page in Wikipedia). **At any rate, pronouncing Spanish, I'm not making that difference**. Maybe it's just accent of mine, but as long as they're not stressed, I don't think Spanish would pronounce very acute *i*-s.

Comment: This answer is very interesting. For what it's worth, the name I wanted to describe is *Yoisel*, which is pronounced in Spanish as *Lloïsel*. Question for native french speakers: Is the pronounciation of the spelling *Lloïsel* the same as *Lloysel* in French?

Comment: @yms: Don't forget in French, a single *s* between two vowels is pronounced `[z]` :p ❚ For that example, I think you can explain it's `yoi-` like in [*yoyo*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo), and `-sel` like… *sel* (salt). And French natives won't pronounce the *s* exactly fine, but you can tell them it's like “-ssel” (*caroussel*) if you want to improve on that. (All of this is assuming I pronounce *Yoisel* correctly, of course.)