# Dans quels contextes utiliser le verbe ouïr ?

Tags: usage, registre-soutenu

Si *ouïr* est considéré vieux, quels sont les contextes dans lesquels ce verbe peut être utilisé de nos jours ?

Comment: Le nom associé, _ouie_, reste actuel.

Comment: Related: [Is 'ouïr' used at all anymore?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2629/217)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On utilise encore *ouï dire* de nos jours :

> J'ai ouï dire qu'un accord a été trouvé. Pourriez-vous le confirmer ?

ceci a donné naissance au mot [*ouï-dire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ou%C3%AF-dire), qui signifie *rumeur* :

> Ce ne sont que des ouï-dires ! Tu ne devrais pas croire ces rumeurs.

Parfois, de façon humoristique, on utilise aussi *oyez* pour annoncer une nouvelle. L'humour vient précisément du fait que cette tournure est désuète : elle veut évoquer [les crieurs publics du moyen-âge](http://www.letelegramme.fr/local/cotes-d-armor/saint-brieuc/ville/crieur-de-rue-gaspard-hazard-porte-parole-des-sans-voix-08-09-2011-1422603.php).

> Oyez oyez bonnes gens ! Les négociations ont abouti, nous allons toucher une prime !

Comment: Donc _ouï-dires_ peut être traduit comme _hearsay_. Et _ouï dire_ comme _to hear one say (something)_? Et _Oyez oyez bonnes gens !_ comme _Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears_ (William Shakespeare, _Julius Caesar_, III, 2)?

Comment: Sans oublier "Ouï-dire" de Raymond Devos http://fr.toluna.com/opinions/446417/Le-dire-Raymond-Devos.htm , de la dentelle francophone donnée comme exercice de choix aux écoliers.

Comment: @indoxica Oui, c'est exactement ça pour "hear one say". Merci beaucoup pour les autres traductions, je ne les connaissais pas ! Concernant "Friends, Romans, ..." ça me semble bien être ça.

Comment: @Shlublu Avec plaisir. Glad I could add something to your linguistic trove.

Comment: À propos du dernier exemple, ça fait une paye que je n'ai pas ouï _oyez_ dans ce contexte précis.

Answer (score 3):

Le seul exemple qui me vient en tête de l'utilisation du verbe *ouïr* est pour cette expression, où il est synonyme du verbe *entendre* et utilisé au participe passé :

> J'ai ouï dire que ce verbe était ancien.

Excepté cette expression, il n'est plus employé dans le langage courant et même cet exemple relève plutôt du langage soutenu.

Answer (score 3):

En plus de *ouï dire* et *oyez*, il y a aussi l'expression:

> Qu'ouïs-je?

Dont le sens est celui du non moins désuet mais bien plus charmant:

> Plaît-il?

---

Il y a aussi l'adjectif:

> inouï

Comment: J'avais oublié que cet adjectif venait de ouïr. Merci du rappel!